# Unable to Ping Raspberry Pi

Tags: networking, ping

I have a Raspberry Pi on my network (via ethernet) that is unable to receive any pings.

I try to ping it from a computer on the network but it times out. I can SSH into the Pi just fine. I can connect to the internet, use SSH, etc on the Pi.

I have fail2ban on the Pi but stopped it. I tried to allow ICMP with this

```
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT  && iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT && iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 0 -j ACCEPT && iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 0 -j ACCEPT
```

but it didn't change anything.

What's going on?

Comment: what IP address are you trying to ping. is it the same IP address as in the output of `ip addr`?

Comment: It's the right one. I can SSH into the Pi just fine.

Comment: Oh. Because use ssh on pi could mean ssh out not in. That's why i asked

Comment: sorry i didn't specify.

Comment: all good, just wanted to be clear

Comment: Have you made iptables complete transparent and then tried to ping?